# How to call a scope method from a button displayed in ngGrid -in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
angular.module('harbinger').controller(
   'Admin.UserlistController',  
   function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $http, userService)
   {
      // etc
      $scope.gridOptions = {
         // etc ,
         enableRowSelection: false,
         columnDefs: [
            {field: 'userName', displayName: 'Username'},
            {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
            {field: 'organization', displayName: 'Organization'},
            {field: 'title', displayName: 'Title'},
            {field: 'dateOfBirth', displayName: 'Date Of Birth'},   
            {field: 'controls', displayName: '', cellTemplate: '<div id="controls" ><a id="user-edit" onClick="editUser(\'{{row.entity.userName}}\')">Edit</a> | <a id="user-reset" data-ng-click="resetUser(\'{{row.entity.userName}}\')">Reset</a> | <a id="user-unlock">Un-lock</a></div>'}
         ]
      };
```

onclick of user reset i have to pass the

```
userService.reset($scope.userData, function( data ) // success
                {
                   // etc
                }
```

i am  using ngGrid, and i am trying to call a scope method from a button displayed in ngGrid. –

on click i am not able to execute this function .
Please give me angular js way to do this .

Comment: Could you please add the html code? Or better a jsfiddle?

Comment: Check your browser console for the errors!

Comment: @DadoJerry : its not showing any error,on page load it will work

Comment: @Kersten  <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" style="display:none"></div>

Comment: supposed to see the html that your are triggering `ng-click()`

Comment: Couldn't you use ng-click?

Comment: @DadoJerry i am using   {field: 'controls', displayName: '', cellTemplate: '<div id="controls" ><a id="user-edit" ng-click="editUser(\'{{row.entity.userName}}\')">Edit</a> | <a id="user-reset" ng-click="resetUser(\'{{row.entity.userName}}   \')">Reset</a> | <a id="user-unlock">Un-lock</a></div>'} in js

Comment: It would help if you mentioned that you're using ngGrid, and that you trying to call a scope method from a button displayed in ngGrid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's an old question but I'll answer it.

`ngGrid` creates an isolated scope so there is no way of getting to your parent scope via something like this:

1. `$parent.editUser('')`
2. `<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl"><div ng-grid="options"></div></div>` and `ctrl.editUser('')`
3. by using `.` (`$scope.callback = {}; $scope.callback.editUser = function(){};` -> `callback.editUser('')`)

`ngGrid` uses your `options` in the isolated scope, which is available to your `cell/rowTemplates` - so you can do as follows:

**Javascript Controller:**

```
$scope.editUser = function(userName) {
    ...
};

$scope.options = {
    data: 'data',
    columnDefs: [{
        field:'name', 
        displayName:'name', 
        cellTemplate: '<div ng-click="options.editUser(\'{{row.entity.userName}}\')">Edit</div>'
    }],
    editUser: $scope.editUser
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-grid="options"></div>
```

**Plunker:**
[Test app](http://plnkr.co/edit/hgTQ1XdEVRyxscoNs76q)