# How to call a scope method from a button displayed in ui-grid - in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I would like to create a custom column with a link and call $scope method on ng-click.
There is very similar question for ngGrid ([How to call a scope method from a button displayed in ngGrid -in Angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362049/how-to-call-a-scope-method-from-a-button-displayed-in-nggrid-in-angular-js)) and that solution works.
I'm using the ui-grid, which is supposed to be just a newer version of ngGrid, but it doesn't seem to work there.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {  
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [{name: 'test'}],
      columnDefs: [{
        field:'name', 
        displayName:'name', 
        cellTemplate: '<div ng-click="gridOptions.editUser()">Edit</div>'
      }],
      editUser: $scope.editUser
    };

  $scope.editUser = function() {
    alert('It works!');
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5SuIeAPFpZaUKbmIDCn

Here is the original solution for ngGrid that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/hgTQ1XdEVRyxscoNs76q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare [external scope](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_externalScopes) that you are going to use in cell templates using `external-scopes` attribute:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" external-scopes="gridScope"></div>
```

Then in controller you need to define this scope object:

```
$scope.gridScope = {
    editUser: function() {
        alert('It works!');
    }
}
```

and finally you access this external scope in template as

```
cellTemplate: '<div ng-click="getExternalScopes().editUser()">Edit</div>'
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/saYe6sddbcO76o9qBrNu?p=preview

Comment: this doesn't work anymore. See the answer from Himen

Answer (score 4):

In new version of ui-grid this approach does not work for me. instead i have use appScope core api.
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope

Comment: yes, juste have to put in your template : ng-click="grid.appScope.your_function(row.entity.your_variable)